# Using Comparison Operators Between Datasets and Vectors in R: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: r

I want to use comparison operators between vectors and dataframes. Say, for example, I have a vector `vector_test` defined in R as

```
vector_test = c(1, 2, 3)
```

and a corresponding dataframe `A_test` defined as

```
A_test = data.frame(
               x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
               x2 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
               x3 = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
)
```

I want to use `vector_test` for isolating which elements in `A_test` are greater than / equal to the elements in `vector_test`. I want the output to be something like

```
A_test >= vector_test

> TRUE  TRUE        .
  TRUE. TRUE.       .
  TRUE. TRUE.       .
  TRUE.  ...        .
  TRUE.  ...        TRUE
```

But instead I got

[image]

It sounds dumb, I know, but I can't figure out (a) what I'm doing wrong and (b) what comparison R is making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What appears to be happening is that the dataframe is coerced to a matrix which is then coerced to a vector for comparison, and the result is converted back to a matrix.

The vector version of `A_test` is

```
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
  3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

When you compare that to a length 3 vector, the vector is first recycled to length 15, giving this:

```
c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2,
  3, 1, 2, 3, 1,
  2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

and then elements are compared to the vector from the dataframe.  The only FALSE in `A_test >= vector_test` comes in the 6th entry.  When converted back to a matrix, that's the first entry in the 2nd column, as you saw.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Man I was wracking my brain trying to understand what was happening! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You need `t`ranspose the matrix first, compare, then transpose back.

```
> t(t(A_test) >= vector_test)
       x1   x2   x3
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

This way you can make proper use of recycling.

It's similar to other arithmetic operations such as addition, multiplication, etc. Let's demonstrate addition on a matrix out of zeros with same dimensions like A_test.

```
> (M <- array(0, dim=dim(A_test)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0
```

What you did is similar to:

```
> M + vector_test
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    2
[2,]    2    1    3
[3,]    3    2    1
[4,]    1    3    2
[5,]    2    1    3
```

What you want is:

```
> t(t(M) + vector_test)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    3
[4,]    1    2    3
[5,]    1    2    3
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(vector_test)
c(1, 2, 3)
> dput(A_test)
structure(list(x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), x2 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
    x3 = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for row-wise comparisons of your data frame to your vector. Perhaps you want

```r
t(apply(A_test, 1, `>=`, vector_test))
#>        x1   x2   x3
#> [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

What R was doing was automatically recycling your length 3 vector 5 times, then comparing this to the three columns of your data frame stacked as one big vector. If we do this explicitly, we'll see we get the same as your initial result:

```r
vector_test_long <- rep(vector_test, 4)

vector_test_long
#>  [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

A_test >= vector_test_long
#>        x1    x2   x3
#> [1,] TRUE FALSE TRUE
#> [2,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE
#> [3,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE
#> [4,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE
#> [5,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! What comparisons was R doing?

Comment: @JerBear recycling - see my update